# AWS SNS: how to send message to topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I use this code to send but during the execution it hangs indefinitely on PublishAsync.
What is the reason? How to fix it?

```
using System;

using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
            SendMessage(client).Wait();
        }

        static async Task SendMessage(IAmazonSimpleNotificationService snsClient)
        {
            var request = new PublishRequest
            {
                TopicArn = "INSERT TOPIC ARN",
                Message = "Test Message"
            };

            await snsClient.PublishAsync(request);
        }
    }
```

This function hangs in WinForms app:

```
 public async Task<string> PublishMessageHandler103(string messageText, string msgGroup)
 {
     try
     {
         string topicArn = topicarn;
         var awsCredentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(accKey, secKey);
         var client = new Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.AmazonSimpleNotificationSer‌​viceClient(awsCreden‌​tials, regionEndpoint);
         var request = new PublishRequest
         {
             TopicArn = topicArn,
             Message = messageText,
             MessageGroupId = msgGroup
         };
         var response = await client.PublishAsync(request);// <----Hangs
         Console.WriteLine($"Successfully published message ID: {response.MessageId}");
         return $"Message Published: {msg}";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("\n\n{0}", ex.Message);
     }
     return "Hmmm";
 }
```

Comment: Hanging indefinitely on an AWS API call usually indicates you are running this code in an environment that doesn't have access to the Internet, or access to an AWS API VPC endpoint. Can you give more details as to how and where you are running this code?

Comment: I run it on my local machine, it has an internet etc. Below i have added the comment: in NET6 Console app it works but the same code in WinForms (NET6) app it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

This .NET code looks fine. I just executed this C# code in Visual Studio and it worked fine.

```
// Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
// SPDX - License - Identifier: Apache - 2.0

namespace PublishToSNSTopicExample
{
    // snippet-start:[SNS.dotnetv3.PublishToSNSTopicExample]
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
    using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model;

    /// <summary>
    /// This example publishes a message to an Amazon Simple Notification
    /// Service (Amazon SNS) topic. The code uses the AWS SDK for .NET and
    /// .NET Core 5.0.
    /// </summary>
    public class PublishToSNSTopic
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            string topicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:814548047983:scott1111";
            string messageText = "This is an example message to publish to the ExampleSNSTopic.";

            IAmazonSimpleNotificationService client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient();

            await PublishToTopicAsync(client, topicArn, messageText);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Publishes a message to an Amazon SNS topic.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client">The initialized client object used to publish
        /// to the Amazon SNS topic.</param>
        /// <param name="topicArn">The ARN of the topic.</param>
        /// <param name="messageText">The text of the message.</param>
        public static async Task PublishToTopicAsync(
            IAmazonSimpleNotificationService client,
            string topicArn,
            string messageText)
        {
            var request = new PublishRequest
            {
                TopicArn = topicArn,
                Message = messageText,
            };

            var response = await client.PublishAsync(request);

            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully published message ID: {response.MessageId}");
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[SNS.dotnetv3.PublishToSNSTopicExample]
}
```

[image]

Check the ARN of the topic and check your network connectivity. The .NET code works. You can find this example and others for this service in the AWS Code Library.

[Amazon SNS examples using AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/csharp_3_sns_code_examples.html)

UPDATE

I just noticed something about your code. You use:

**SendMessage(client).Wait();**

In AWS example, its:

**await PublishToTopicAsync(client, topicArn, messageText);**

Comment: I have used the code in NET6 Console app; finally it works fine after I have added to request  MessageGroupId, without it it was an error. But I have copied the code to my WinForms app it hangs ...

Comment: I am checking with team to see if anyone seen this for this project type

Comment: Thnx. Note: my WinForms (NET6). Also , my SNS Topic FIFO, thats why it requires MessageGroupId

Comment: See my update. At 1st, I did not notice that .

Comment: I use await SendMessage but it is my function, it calls await PublishAsync (see my code above again)

Comment: Please take a look at my updated start post

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Forms

```
 var response = await client.PublishAsync(request);// <----Hangs
```

and this way works fine

```
 var response = await client.PublishAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);//OK!
```